# What's wrong with my collision detection?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a simple interactive game on my webpage:

[image: Small map game]

1. This is a map-based game. There is a blue box and a red box.
2. Use arrow keys (left, right, up, and down) to move the blue box on the map. (I have done that already.)
3. When the blue box (id name "*hehao*") **overlaps** the red box (id name "*london*"), a hidden div with the class name "*londonClass*" will pop out. This is my problem: the hidden div does NOT pop out.

   ```
   function checkOverlap () {

   //get the position of the blue box
   var hh = document.getElementById('hehao');
   var rect1 = hh.getBoundingClientRect();

   //get the position of the red box
   var london = document.getElementById('london'); 
   var rect2 = london.getBoundingClientRect();

   //compare the positions of two boxes
   var overlap =  !(rect1.right < rect2.left ||
                    rect1.left > rect2.right || 
                    rect1.bottom < rect2.top || 
                    rect1.top > rect2.bottom);

   //if the two boxes overlap, then display the hidden div.
   var londonClass = document.getElementsByClassName('londonClass');
   if(overlap) { 
       londonClass.style.display = "block";
   }
   }

   document.ready = checkOverlap();
   ```

Comment: Your code is quite incomplete, or not representative of your actual code: you're using `londonClass` which is not defined anywhere. I recommend you set up a jsFiddle to demonstrate your issue. Also, don't hesitate to add `console.log` statements in all relevant places in your code to trace what actually happens (or use your favorite browser's Javascript debugger).

Comment: Your overlap logic is wrong.  Spend more time with paper and pencil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic for calculating the overlap is wrong. This is the correct one:

```
(rect1.right > rect2.left && rect2.right > rect1.left) &&
(rect1.bottom > rect2.top && rect2.bottom > rect1.top)
```

**And here is an example to find this out *(just run it and play with the x/y values)*:**

```js
var interval1 = setInterval(function() {
 var rect1 = document.querySelector('.rect1');
 var rect2 = document.querySelector('.rect2');
 
 (function updatePosition() {
  rect1.style.left = document.querySelector('.rect1inputLeft').value + "px"
  rect1.style.top = document.querySelector('.rect1inputTop').value + "px";
  rect2.style.left = document.querySelector('.rect2inputLeft').value + "px";
  rect2.style.top = document.querySelector('.rect2inputTop').value + "px";
 })();
 
 (function updateRectangleValues() {
  var rect1rectangle = rect1.getBoundingClientRect();
  var rect2rectangle = rect2.getBoundingClientRect();
  
  var newrect1 = '<span style="position: absolute; top: 2px; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);">' + rect1rectangle.top + "</span>"
   + '<span style="position: absolute; top: 50%; right: 2px; transform: translateY(-50%);">' + rect1rectangle.right + "</span>"
   + '<span style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 2px; transform: translateY(-50%);">' + rect1rectangle.left + "</span>"
   + '<span style="position: absolute; bottom: 2px; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);">' + rect1rectangle.bottom + "</span>";
  var newrect2 = '<span style="position: absolute; top: 2px; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);">' + rect2rectangle.top + "</span>"
   + '<span style="position: absolute; top: 50%; right: 2px; transform: translateY(-50%);">' + rect2rectangle.right + "</span>"
   + '<span style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 2px; transform: translateY(-50%);">' + rect2rectangle.left + "</span>"
   + '<span style="position: absolute; bottom: 2px; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);">' + rect2rectangle.bottom + "</span>";
      
  if(rect1.innerHTML !== newrect1) {
   rect1.innerHTML = newrect1;
  }
  if(rect2.innerHTML !== newrect2) {
   rect2.innerHTML = newrect2;
  }

  (function checkIfOverlapping() {
   document.querySelector('.overlapping').checked = ((rect1rectangle.right > rect2rectangle.left && rect2rectangle.right > rect1rectangle.left) && (rect1rectangle.bottom > rect2rectangle.top && rect2rectangle.bottom > rect1rectangle.top));
  })();

 })();
 
}, 50);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.rect {
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.7;
  color: white;
}
.rect1 {
  background: green;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.rect2 {
  background: blue;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.rect1input {
  background: green;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.rect2input {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.rect1input, .rect2input {
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  padding-left: 3px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="rect rect1"></div>
<div class="rect rect2"></div>
x <input type="number" class="rect1input rect1inputLeft" value="100">
y <input type="number" class="rect1input rect1inputTop" value="60"> &nbsp; &nbsp;
x <input type="number" class="rect2input rect2inputLeft" value="100">
y <input type="number" class="rect2input rect2inputTop" value="132">
&nbsp; &nbsp;
overlapping? <input type="checkbox" class="overlapping" disabled>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I spent several hours in studying your codes and finally got it.

Comment: @Hao Great! :) You can upvote and accept the answer if you like to by clicking on ✔ and ▲ on the left side.